# Craft 3: with Base URL of site set up using @web alias, how to display the original URL in Twig templates?

Tags: templating, craft3, multi-site

I use the `@web` alias in the configuration of the base URLs of the sites (following [Craft 3 documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/#aliases)). The `@web` alias allows a shortcut  to the URL of the folder that contains the `index.php` file loaded for the request.

However, when I loop through `craft.app.sites.getAllSites` using Twig, the value of baseUrl still prints `@web` in the URL, instead of transform it in its original URL.

As a workaround, I could get the original URL using `{{ craft.app.sites.currentSite.baseUrl ~ site.uri | replace({ '@web': '' }) }}`. But this seems a very dirty solution that will probably not always work.

Comment: The "Craft 3 documentation" link is no longer active.

Comment: Thank you @DavidRhoden, link updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So luckily for us, Brandon recently added the `alias()` Twig function. It should show up in Craft CMS 3 RC7. You can see the discussion about it here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2327